# Authentication just by checking session

Tags: php, session, authentication, cookies

Let's say I have a simple login system.
Upon successful login, user_id and username will be stored in the session.

Provided the cookie used to persist session in the client browser is encrypted, is there anything wrong (or bad, such as a security flaw) with just checking `if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])` for authentication?